# Resized ubuntu partition not showing properly in VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, partition, vmware-workstation, gparted

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 in windows under vmware workstation 11.

I ran out of diskspace on the VM (I had it set it to 30GB). Within the VM Properties - I have expanded the diskspace to 60GB.

I ran gparted on boot and resized the partition /dev/sda2 (ext) to use the unallocated space. and then resize /dev/sda5 (lvm) to take up the space.

When I rebooted the VM I ran `df -h` and it not showing the proper diskspace increase.

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   26G   14G   11G  56% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        394M  3.3M  391M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M   78M  146M  35% /boot
```

I have ran `lvextend --size +30G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` - then `lvdisplay`

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                wCuSu5-h5eH-3Gvy-IB9N-F1CE-Vrv7-jD6jHm
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2015-06-16 11:09:09 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                55.76 GiB
  Current LE             14274
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

I have rebooted. Still no volume change. I'm lost.

Comment: Did you `resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root` after you extended the LV?

Comment: @womble please put what you wrote as the answer. It worked and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step you've missed is that after you've resized the Logical Volume, you need to then resize the filesystem that is in that LV.  For ext[234] filesystems, you can do this "online" (with the filesystem mounted) by running

```
ext2resize /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

If the LV is formatted with another filesystem, check its documentation for the correct way to resize it.